# How do you debug a POST request that is running on an in memory server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So I'm trying to test my API using an in memory Http Server, as advised by this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2013/01/28/writing-tests-for-an-asp-net-webapi-service.aspx

My code looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void AddNewCustomer()
    {
        config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        HttpServer server = new HttpServer(config);
        using (HttpMessageInvoker client = new HttpMessageInvoker(server))
        {
            using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/Customer"))

            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(@"{ ""Email"" : ""me@you.com"", ""Password"" : ""password"" }");
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None).Result)
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

I've tried testing the actual API, which works, when I post a customer it responds correctly. When I try testing it with this, the response.StatusCode is 'internal server error'.

That's irritating, but what's more confusing is that I find myself unable to debug what's actually going wrong - I don't know why it's getting this error in this environment, and I can't stick break points in to test what's happening.

EDIT: My response body is just:

```
        "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any error message in the response body?

Comment: You should debug it with Feddle and then post the HTTP response code from the API here!

Comment: You can just write the response body to the console: `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`

Comment: The response body is just:

  "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following after new HttpConfiguration()

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```